# Arrow keys not working in CLIPS?

Tags: clips, arrow-keys

For some reason, I cannot navigate the CLIPS interpreter with my arrow keys. When I press the left arrow key, I get the escape code ^[[D (and various escape codes for the remaining arrow keys). I'm running Linux and followed the installation steps outlined in section 2.1 and 2.1.1 of the [Advance Programmer's Guide](http://clipsrules.sourceforge.net/documentation/v630/apg.pdf). Please note that I am using the CLIPS version 6.40 beta 2 release. Also, I verified the sha1 and md5 hashes before extracting the source code.

Steps used to compile:

- Navigated to extracted source directory.
- Entered the command as stated in section 2.1.1 under the UNIX heading `gcc -o clips *.c -lm`.
- Ran compiled program.

To remedy this I have tried:

- Compiling separate interpreters with the -DGENERIC=1 and -DLINUX=1 build flags.
- Re-downloading the source code and recompiling it.
- Downloading and compiling the latest stable (version 6.30) of CLIPS using the same steps outlined above.
- Using the makefile included in each version to compile rather than using gcc.

Aside from this issue, CLIPS seems to be working fine. I talked to one of my peers that's using the Windows version, and he is able to navigate with the arrow keys just fine.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use of the arrow keys at the CLIPS command prompt is not supported in the cross-platform core source code. Use of the arrow keys is supported in the Windows, macOS, and Java Swing Integrated Development Environments.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that for me, and thank you for your development contributions to CLIPS!